# When is LICQ useful in KKT conditions?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

KKT establishes a set of criteria for differentiable optimisation problems related to strong duality (i.e. when primal optimal equals dual optimal). In particular, KKT conditions are necessary for strong duality in all cases, and also sufficient when the primal problem becomes convex (i.e. when the objective and inequality constraints all become convex and the equality constraints are affine).

However, in one of my class slides it presents a different version of KKT conditions with the additional LICQ (i.e. *active* inequality constraints and equality constraints have linearly independent gradients). I'm really confused why LICQ is needed here at all. Does requiring LICQ additionally improve or generalise the usual LICQ-free version of KKT? I don't see how it can (the conclusion the slide shows doesn't seem strengthened, despite requiring more). So I'm curious to know where LICQ can come into play. Thanks.

Comment: How does LICQ change the KKT conditions other than turning them into necessary conditions?

Comment: @LinAlg it seems that in Boyd's book there's no mention of LICQ in the KKT conditions.

Comment: LICQ is an alternative to Slater's condition

Comment: Vandenberghe and Boyd use Slater's condition rather than LICQ.  You need some kind of constraint qualification to make the KKT conditions necessary- there are many constraint qualification conditions.

Comment: @BrianBorchers thanks. May I ask a converse question: if the problem is convex and $C^1$,  KKT conditions are satisfied, but no CQ is assumed, then does it necessarily imply optimality? (Namely are KKT still sufficient?)

Comment: @Vim, yes- for a convex problem, if the KKT conditions are satisfied then the KKT condition are sufficient to ensure optimality..  The converse- "If $x^{*}$ is optimal than the KKT conditions are satisfied" requires a constraint qualification.  There are convex optimization problems with optimal solutions but no KKT points.

Comment: @BrianBorchers this exactly solves my problem. If you don't mind, would you like to post this comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's possible for a convex optimization problem to have an optimal solution but no KKT points.  Constraint qualifications such as Slater's condition, LICQ, MFCQ, etc. are necessary to ensure that an optimal solution will satisfy the KKT conditions.

For example, consider the problem

$\min x_{2}$

subject to

$(x_{1}-1)^{2}+x_{2}^{2} \leq 1$

$(x_{1}+1)^{2}+x_{2}^{2} \leq 1$

Here, the only feasible point is $x^{*}_{1}=0$, $x^{*}_{2}=0$.  Thus that point is an optimal solution.  However, you can check and you'll find that the KKT conditions are not satisfied at $x^{*}$.